# How to extract a particular data between 2 strings from a text file In sequence or a control manner If more than one such Instances are met

Tags: perl

```
Sample Input Data file :
================

Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
temp data here
Rocky1
Rocky2
Rocky3
Rocky4
CSeq: 3 REGISTER

Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
temp data here
Jocky1
Jocky2
Jocky3
Jocky4
CSeq: 3 REGISTER

Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
Hello
world
Bye
temp data here
CSeq: 3 REGISTER
```

e.g. In the above data I want to extract data between variable 1 -> Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER) and variable 2->CSeq: 3 REGISTER

temp data here

```
Rocky1
Rocky2
Rocky3
Rocky4
```

Now as there are multiple occurrences of variable 1 and variable 2 In the below Input file but the data Is different so want to control each occurrence of these variables to manipulate further.

Below Is the program used to extract data which Is actually extracting data from all the occurrences but does not have control If I wish to extract till only first occurrence of variable 1 and variable 2

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = "output.txt";


my $kw1 = "Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)";
my $kw2 = "CSeq: 3 REGISTER";   

while (<DATA>) {

   if ( /\Q$kw2\E/ ... /\Q$kw1\E/ ) {
      print;
   }
}
```

Added the recent Issue here

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $kw1 = 'Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)';
my $kw2 = 'CSeq: 3 REGISTER';

my $instance_counter;
my @first;
my @next;
my $myfile = "Input.txt";
open my $out_file1, '>', 'hello1.txt' or die "$!";
open my $out_file2, '>', 'hello2.txt' or die "$!";


open DATA, $myfile or die "Can't open file: $!";

while (<DATA>) {
    if (my $match = (/\Q$kw1/ .. /\Q$kw2/)) {
        ++$instance_counter if 1 == $match;

        if (1 == $instance_counter) {
            push @first, $_ if /$kw1/;

        } else {
            @next = @first if 1 == $match;
            shift @next;
            push @next , $_;
        }


    }
    print $out_file1 @first;
    print $out_file2 @next;
}
```

Lets say below Is my Input data :

```
Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
temp data here
Rocky1
Rocky2
Rocky3
Rocky4
I don't know the text here
CSeq: 3 REGISTER

Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
temp data here
Jocky1
Jocky2
Jocky3
Jocky4
I don't know the text here
CSeq: 3 REGISTER


I want my output to look like as 

output_1.txt
temp data here
Rocky1
Rocky2
Rocky3
Rocky4
I don't know the text here

output_2.txt
temp data here
Jocky1
Jocky2
Jocky3
Jocky4
I don't know the text here


#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $kw1 = 'Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)';
my $kw2 = 'CSeq: 3 REGISTER';

my $instance_counter;
my @first;
my @next;
my $myfile = "Input.txt";
open my $out_file1, '>', 'hello1.txt' or die "$!";
open my $out_file2, '>', 'hello2.txt' or die "$!";
open my $out_file3, '>', 'hello3.txt' or die "$!";

open DATA, $myfile or die "Can't open file: $!";

while (<DATA>) {
    if (my $match = (/\Q$kw1/ .. /\Q$kw2/)) {
        ++$instance_counter if 1 == $match;

        if (1 == $instance_counter) {
          print $out_file1 $_;
        } 
        elsif (2 == $instance_counter){
        print $out_file2 $_;
        }
        else {
           print $out_file3 $_;
        }


    }

}
```

I am now getting In separate output files. Can I generalize It for any no of Instances being found from a file ?

Comment: How large is your source file?

Comment: My source file Is quite large so unable to share here.approx 10MB in size with complex data to be manipulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1: you have the range backwards, it should start at $kw1 and end at $kw2. Also, it's unlcear why you used `...` instead of `..`, as both the expressions never match on the same line.

Note that the range operator return the iteration number, with `E0` at the end for the last line, so you can easily catch when the last expression matches:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    if (my $match = (/\Q$kw1/ .. /\Q$kw2/)) {
        print;
        last if $match =~ /E0/;
    }
}
```

So, to compare the first instance with each other, you can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $kw1 = 'Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)';
my $kw2 = 'CSeq: 3 REGISTER';

my $instance_counter;
my @first;
my @next;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (my $match = (/\Q$kw1/ .. /\Q$kw2/)) {
        ++$instance_counter if 1 == $match;

        if (1 == $instance_counter) {
            push @first, $_ if /ocky\d/;

        } else {
            @next = @first if 1 == $match;
            shift @next if /ocky\d/
                        && substr($_, 1) eq substr $next[0], 1;
        }

        if ($match =~ /E0$/ && $instance_counter > 1) {
            if (@next) {
                say scalar @next, " ockies missing in instance $instance_counter";
            } else {
                say "instance $instance_counter ok";
            }
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
temp data here
Rocky1
Rocky2
Rocky3
Rocky4
CSeq: 3 REGISTER

Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
temp data here
Jocky1
Jocky2
Jocky3
Jocky4
CSeq: 3 REGISTER

Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
Qocky1
Qocky2
Hello
world
Bye
temp data here
CSeq: 3 REGISTER
```

Comment: actually I want to compare the data extracted from the very first occurrence with similar data from another file. then move to the last .so Interested only In the control where I can stop at first occurrence Itself

Comment: Feel free to modify the code to your liking, now you know how to recognise the end of a block.

Comment: Oh wait, you want to `last if /\Q$kw1/` only?

Comment: > last if $match =~ /E0/; Is matching to one occurrence correctly but how can I get the other occurrences one by one ?

Comment: @rocky But you are getting them one by one in the loop. If you need them later, `push` them into an array.

Comment: the loop always picks up the same instance (i.e. first match) only and I want all instances.

Comment: Is there any way I can play with each occurrence using $match =~ /E0/;

Comment: @rocky: If you want all instances, don't call `last`, but do whatever else you like to do at the end of a block. `$match` will be 1 at the start of a new instance.

Comment: by using $match ==100 i can get intial few lines of ist contexts but I have 2 Issues here. 1) -> my Instances lengths are not fixed so I can not rely on the no of lines using $match. 2) how to get the second Instance as $match starts from 1 but I don;t know where In my file second Instance starts from ?

Comment: @rocky: OK, once again. `$match` will be 1 for line 1 of **every** instance. You don't need to know how each instance is long, `$match` will end in `E0` for the last line of **every** instance. You can recognize the number of an instance by keeping a counter and incrementing it every time a new instance starts, maybe.

Comment: Ok My First Issue Is resolved now. For the second Issue I am still confused as I don;t know when my second Instance Is starting as per you each instance Is ending with E0 so how to differentiate b/w 2 Instances.

Comment: You can recognize the number of an instance by keeping a counter and incrementing it every time a new instance starts, maybe => can you pls help on this how can I move to the next Instance after finishing with first one ?

Comment: For each Instance $match Is from 1 to E0 but what Is the count for each Instance here . how can we do It ?

Comment: Can you please explaing why do we need to match for In $_ if /ocky\d/;
and the purpose of substr($_, 1) eq substr $next[0], 1;

Comment: Can you please help how can I extract each Instant Into a different output file say Instance_1.txt , Instance_2.txt so on as It would be easy to operate directly on the each instances in text file further. thanks

Comment: My code is an example, it checks that each instance has the same sequence of ?ocky as the first one. You can do whatever test you like in your code, just use the scaffolding - you can easily see what happens for each line, and what happens at the end of an instance. I also showed how to store an instance into an array. What else do you need?

Comment: what In case my Instance does not end with the same line so how  will get the Instance array for each Instance.

Comment: @rocky: OK, so how do you recongnise the end of an instance?

Comment: I know only $kw1 and $kw2 but not the text ?ocky In between as for a large Input file It would be difficult to open and check ?ocky like strings so  I have 2 problem - 1. how to take the Instance between $kw1 and $kw2 2. how to extract each instance separately Into a text file

Comment: I have update the problem more clearly above In the header

Comment: Don't break my code, please. You can update your question if you like. But basically, if you want to print to a file, just do it. Do you know how to print to a file?

Comment: Oops! my mistake I did it.

Comment: Added the latest Issue + code Above In my question. Actually I tried to print to files but did not get the desired output In output files.

Comment: You don't need `@next`. Just print direcly instead of pushing.

Comment: Can I generalize It for any no of Instances being found from a file ? In the above code I knew there were 3 Instance what about If i don;t know the no of Instances In a file and want the output In n number of file ..

Comment: You should create a new question to ask a new question. If you feel the old question is related, you can link to it from the new one.

Comment: I have opened another question named - How to generalize the pattern matching search from a file using range operator in Perl

Answer (score 0):

You have blank lines after each record. Therefore I'd suggest what you need is to look at `$/`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = "output.txt";


my $kw1 = "Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)";
my $kw2 = "CSeq: 3 REGISTER";

local $/ = '';
while (<DATA>) {
   next unless m/^Session/;
   s/Session Initiation Protocol.*//gm;
   s/^CSeq.*//gm;

   print "\nStart of record\n";
   print;
   print "\nEnd of Record\n";
}


__DATA__
Sample Input Data file :
================

Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
temp data here
Rocky1
Rocky2
Rocky3
Rocky4
CSeq: 3 REGISTER

Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
temp data here
Jocky1
Jocky2
Jocky3
Jocky4
CSeq: 3 REGISTER

Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
Hello
world
Bye
temp data here
CSeq: 3 REGISTER
```

This way, each iteration of the look will have a single 'record' that you can process.

Alternatively, you could create an array of records using (something like) `split` or a repeat regex.

Comment: I did not get any output on the screen. I think It's better to extract the each occurrence Into some file and then manipulate.

Comment: This works for the data provided. I can't begin to guess why it doesn't work for you.